# Can I change the status code used for the NotFoundPage in google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, single-page-application

It looks like when Google Cloud Storage serves the desired object for a `NotFoundPage`, it includes the status code `404`.

Is there any way to set it so that the content is served with a `200` status?  This will make it easier for any single page applications I deploy to the bucket to manage their own deep linking.

Comment: I have to think there's another reasonable way to do what you want that's more disciplined than this. Changing the status code on the server side this way seems a little extreme.

Comment: It's extremely common for single page applications to manage their own routing, so an internal redirect is usually how this is done.  All URLs correctly resolve, and then it's left to the application to determine if something is found.

Comment: I completely spaced out and missed the "serves the desired object" part — sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as though this is currently a feature request over at the Google Cloud issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151212194

I encourage anyone who arrives here to head over there and star the issue and also comment to help get this some priority.

Comment: Even after these many years, it is still not supported!

Comment: Yeap.  Be sure to upvote that GCP issue ticket, comment, share, get friends to upvote, make noise.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the status code on a Flutter SPA by using the Load Balancer's Advanced Routing Rules:

- Edit the Load Balancer
- Click Routing Rules
- Change Mode to "Advanced host and path rule"
- Click ADD HOST AND PATH RULE
- Enter * for the Hosts field
- Enter the following, depending on your URL format - eg. if the URL I want to rewrite/fix status code on is formatted as: `website.com/products/12345/my-amazing-product` then I would enter:

```
defaultService: projects/{..your-project-name..}/global/backendBuckets/{..your-backend-name..}
name: products
routeRules:
- matchRules:
  - pathTemplateMatch: /products/*/*
  priority: 10
  service: projects/{..your-project-name..}/global/backendBuckets/{..your-backend-name..}
  routeAction:
    urlRewrite:
      pathTemplateRewrite: /index.html
```

*Thanks [@Alexander Trauzzi](/users/128991/alexander-trauzzi) for linking the Google issue - [comment #48](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151212194#comment48) there gave me the idea to try the advanced routing.*

Comment: Hah!  That's pretty neat actually, will definitely keep in mind.